# XPath does not recognize the "|" condition

Tags: xml, xpath

XPath newbie.

I would like to extract the ascending sibling's attribute @id in the XML below, but when no such sibling exists
to show the ascending parent's id. (The next step will be to go from that parent to the next node that contains an id). Basically parsing the file for all ids.

(That gets me thinking: Maybe I just need to search for the next id, regardless of sibling or parent).

Well here is my current issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <parent class="InfoType01" id="1">
    <p>11</p>
        <node class="InfoType01" id="2">
            <p>22</p>
        </node>
        <node class="InfoType01" id="3">
            <p>33</p>
        </node>
  </parent>
</root>
```

Here is my XPath expression:

```
//node[contains(p, '33')]/preceding-sibling::node[@class='InfoType01'][1]/@id
| 
//node[contains(p, '33')]/ancestor::*[@class='InfoType01']/@id
```

each of them works perfectly n its owm:

The first row searches for the asc sibling (here 22), and if I start with "22" it returns nothing.

The second one finds the parent.

According to the XPATH spec, the "|" should function as follows:
"If the first expression does not return anything, move on the the seconds one.

Unfortunately it does not do that, the expression always will go the the parent search,
even if the child search returns a value.

I am stumped.

Thanks!!

BTW: I tested this with https://www.atatus.com/tools/xpath-validator

Comment: Can your link to that "XPATH spec" you quote? For me for XPath 1.0 the relevant spec is https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-sets and says "The `|` operator computes the union of its operands, which must be node-sets" and for the current version 3.1 is at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#combining_seq and says "The `union` and `|` operators are equivalent. They take two node sequences as operands and return a sequence containing all the nodes that occur in either of the operands.[..]these operators eliminate duplicate nodes from their result sequences based on node identity".

Comment: Unfortunately the free formatter does not work either and returns both... Attribute='id=1'
Attribute='id=2'
One frustrating issue I have found is that the online test-beds all give slightly different results.
@Martin: I did not mean "spec"  I found it "somewhere on the internet" in my many attempts...

Comment: Now that you have two links to the spec sections and quotes I hope the term "union" of nodes makes it clearer as to what `|` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `not()` predicate of the `ancestor::*` like this:

```
//node[contains(p, '33')]/preceding-sibling::node[@class='InfoType01'][1]/@id 
| 
//node[contains(p, '33')][not(preceding-sibling::node[@class='InfoType01'])]/ancestor::*[@class='InfoType01']/@id
```

Comment: That actually does seem to work!!  Now I just need to understand it :-)
and it seems that the | operator does work like   "return condition1 if no result try condition 2"

Thanks a lot Siebe

Answer (score 0):

> According to the XPATH spec, the "|" should function as follows: "If the first expression does not return anything, move on the the seconds one.

Where did you find that? It's nonsense. Even if you did `(A|B)[1]` it would be wrong, because the result of `(A|B)` is always in document order. With XPath 2.0 the idiom `(A,B)[1]` is common. The draft XPath 4.0 spec offers `A otherwise B`.

What you can do in XPath 1.0 is `(A|B)[last()]`, which finds the node that is last in document order.